# AngularJS ng-show - sg-hide -ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-show

How to get a start button that hides when clicked and display a stop button .
When I click the stop button I want to see appear the start button .
I tried this but it does not.
Someone has an idea ?

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('djoro.controllers')
.controller('WifiSmartConfigCtrl', function($scope, $window, $ionicPlatform){
  $scope.EventRunning = false;
  $scope.showAlert = function(){
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
      $window.cordova.plugins.Smartconfig.alert('My plugin works !');
    });
  };
  $scope.startSmartconfig = function(){
    var onSuccess = function(success){
      $scope.StartEvent = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $scope.EventRunning = true;
      };
    };
    var onFail = function(){};
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
      $window.cordova.plugins.Smartconfig.startSmartconfig(onSuccess, onFail, wifiPassword);
    });
  };
  $scope.stopSmartconfig = function(){
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
      var onSuccess = function(){
        $scope.StopEvent = function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $scope.EventRunning = true;
        };
        alert("stopSmartconfig done");
      };
      var onFail = function(){};
      $window.cordova.plugins.Smartconfig.stopSmartconfig(onSuccess, onFail);
    });
  };
)};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="startWifi">
                <button ng-hide="EventRunning" class="button button-full button-balanced" ng-click="startSmartconfig($event)">Start</button>
                <button ng-show="EventRunning" class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="stopSmartconfig($event)">Stop</button>
</div>
```

How to get a start button that hides when clicked and display a stop button .
When I click the stop button I want to see appear the start button .
I tried this but it does not.
Someone has an idea ?

Comment: I already use ng- ng- show and hide in the html code .

Comment: Check browser console for error.

Comment: In last line of controller replace `)};` with `});`

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';

angular.module('djoro.controllers')

 .controller('WifiSmartConfigCtrl', function($scope, $window,    $ionicPlatform){

 $scope.EventRunning = false;

  $scope.showAlert = function(){
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
   $window.cordova.plugins.Smartconfig.alert('My plugin works !');
});
};

$scope.startSmartconfig = function(event){

    var onSuccess = function(success){
        $scope.StartEvent = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $scope.EventRunning = true;
        };

    };

    var onFail = function(){};

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){

    $window.cordova.plugins.Smartconfig.startSmartconfig(onSuccess, onFail, wifiPassword);

    });

 };

 $scope.stopSmartconfig = function(event){
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){



      var onSuccess = function(){

        $scope.StopEvent = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $scope.EventRunning = true;
    };

          alert("stopSmartconfig done");
      };
      var onFail = function(){};

      $window.cordova.plugins.Smartconfig.stopSmartconfig(onSuccess, onFail);
    });



     };

   )};
```

you controller methods your calling holds a parameter and you are passing no parameter in the method see the above code

Answer (score 0):

You close your code wrong, I don't know if that is going to fix your problem but it can give other problems so replace this: `)};`, with `});` if you still have the problem check for any errors please.